# SFDC date format for Informatica TO_DATE

Tags: informatica-powercenter

We want to convert the SFDC date format string(2015-04-06T00:00:00Z) into Informatica datetime format using the `TO_DATE(<STRING>, <FORMAT>)` function.
We want to this without using the Substring functions.
Please let me know the FORMAT to be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, and using this function: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ')` 
I am getting this output:
`04/06/2015 00:00:00.000000`
Note the syntax of `TO_DATE(char, [format])`, the *format* parameter is the format of your input, not the format of your expected output.

Some examples here:

INPUT: `2012-1-23T02:09:44.847`
TODATE: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS    ')` (four spaces at end)
OUTPUT: `01/23/2012 02:09:44.000000`

INPUT: `2015/05/12T12:23:34GARBAGE`
TODATE: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS       ')` (seven spaces at end)
OUTPUT: `2015/05/12 12:23:34.000000`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my input format is not "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS". It has T and Z as shown : 2015-04-06T00:00:00Z

Comment: @Venkat Yes, your input is not "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS", but it is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS '`.  Note the space at the end.  The spaces here `DD HH24` and here `MI:SS '` are like saying "there is a character here, but that character is not part of the date".  The Integration Service basically just wants to know where the good parts of the date input are in the current port data it is looking at, and those good parts are specified as 'YYYY', 'MM', etc.